# copying std list with pointers to another std list with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stl

I am trying to copy the value of a list of pointers into another list of pointers. When I delete the allocation of the first pointer the values do not remain in the second list. I know this is specifically because it is a list of pointers and the address is being copied over and not the actual value. I was wondering how I would go about doing this.

the following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::list<int*> pointer_list;

  std::list<int*> int_list;


  int one, two, three, four, five;

  one = 1;
  two = 2;
  three = 3;
  four = 4;
  five = 5;

  pointer_list.push_back(new int(one));
  pointer_list.push_back(new int(two));
  pointer_list.push_back(new int(three));
  pointer_list.push_back(new int(four));
  pointer_list.push_back(new int(five));



  for (std::list<int*>::iterator iterator = pointer_list.begin(), end = pointer_list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << **iterator << std::endl;
  }

  for (std::list<int*>::iterator iterator = pointer_list.begin(), end = pointer_list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
  {
    int_list.push_back(*iterator);
  }

  for (std::list<int*>::iterator iterator = pointer_list.begin(), end = pointer_list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
  {
    delete *iterator;
  }

  for (std::list<int*>::iterator iterator = int_list.begin(), end = int_list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << "INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: " << **iterator << std::endl;
  }

  for (std::list<int*>::iterator iterator = pointer_list.begin(), end = pointer_list.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << "LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: " << **iterator << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

the following is the output:

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: 1469317922
  INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: 1469317925
  INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: 1469317928
  INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: 0
  INT_LIST_AFTER DELETE: 5
  LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: 1469317922
  LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: 1469317925
  LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: 1469317928
  LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: 0
  LIST_POINTER AFTER DELETE: 5
```

Also how would I go about deleting the last element?  When I iterate through the list the condition `iterator != end` prevents it and I cannot use `<=` because of the nature of a list.

Comment: Why are you storing pointers?  If you are just dealing with `int`s use them and drop the pointers.

Comment: "I was wondering how I would go about doing this" - how to go about doing *what* ? You already identified the problem. You have a list full of dangling pointers. So.. either don't use pointers, or use something that can be shared between lists, like `std::shared_ptr<int>` instead of `int*`.

Comment: I am trying to implement a deep copy of one list of pointers to another if possible.

Comment: So don't use pointers *at all*. Use a `std::list<int>`.

Comment: @a-one, you're *getting* a deep copy, as one would ordinarily interpret that in light of the fact that you construe your lists as lists *of pointers*.  The pointer values are copied.  If you want the second list to contain different pointers than the first list, then you'll need to allocate space for them to point to and initialize that space appropriately.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but if I have a class with a list of pointers and I am trying to implement a copy construct that takes a reference to another list of pointers how would I do a deep copy. the int is just arbitrary I am trying to test the concept if that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so would do:  int_list.push_back(new int(*iterator)); ?

Comment: @a-one, at first glance, yes, it looks like that would do it.  Instead of asking me, though, why don't you try it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did I am getting an error: test2.cpp:35:32: error: cannot initialize a new value of type 'int' with an
      lvalue of type 'value_type' (aka 'int *')
        int_list.push_back(new int(*iterator));

Comment: @a-one, my bad.  `*iterator` is the *pointer* value being iterated.  The referenced `int` is `**iterator`, so you want `int_list.push_back(new int(**iterator));`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger got it, Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 1):

Often I use  pointers in std::list or std::vector to avoid copy which improves speed. 
Of course the  example uses pointers of int which makes sense for exemplary only.

```
std::vector<int> list_int;
std::vector<int> list_int_copy;

std::vector<std::unique_ptr< int >> list_heap_unique;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr< int >> list_heap_unique_copy;


for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        list_int.push_back(i);
        //std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(i));
        list_heap_unique.emplace_back(new int(i));// new int(i)); // allocate object to heap memory
        std::cout << i << ": orig i:" <<  list_int.at(i) << ", heap " << *list_heap_unique.at(i) << " ptr 0x" << (void *)list_heap_unique.at(i).get(); // << std::endl;
}

std::copy(list_int.begin(),list_int.end(), std::back_inserter(list_int_copy));

for (int val: list_int_copy) {
       std::cout << "copy val int: "  << val; // << std::endl;
}

std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(list_heap_unique.begin()),
          std::make_move_iterator(list_heap_unique.end()),
          std::back_inserter(list_heap_unique_copy));


std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>::iterator iter;
for (iter = list_heap_unique_copy.begin();
     iter!= list_heap_unique_copy.end();
     ++iter)
{
     int *ptr = (*iter).get();
     if (ptr)
        std::cout << "copy val u_ptr: " << *ptr;// << std::endl;
}
```

With plain pointers it isn`t so hard to delete the content of the container after use. 
It depends how and where you add or remove elements to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Storing *raw* **owning** pointers in STL containers like `std::vector` or `std::list` is a source of bugs and *"leaktrocities"* (e.g. if exceptions are thrown, the allocated resources are leaked, as STL containers' destructors won't deallocate the raw owning pointers).
You should either store *values*, or use *smart* pointers (*observing* raw pointers are fine, if you pay attention to their lifetime).

If you really want to store pointers in STL containers, and you want a *shared ownership* semantic, you may want to consider **`std::shared_ptr`**. E.g. you can have `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>` (`list<shared_ptr<int>>` in your case).

In this case you can perform copy operations, that will translate into *reference count* operations (e.g. when something is copied, instead of a deep-copy, you get an increased reference count; it's all automatically managed by `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Thanks for the help it is much appreciated and did not go unnoticed, the answer to my problem was : int temp = **iterator;
        int_list.push_back(new int(temp));

Comment: Yes, but if one is going to store raw pointers in an STL container, then the kind of copy the OP wants to perform is exactly the kind one *should* perform, as it does not create any (additional) aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for the time as well @John Bollinger

Comment: @a-one: `int_list.push_back(new int(temp))` is _not_ good IMO if `int_list` is a `std::list` storing raw _owning_ pointers. If you want unique ownership, consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`.